# Sharpe Ratio optimization using pyportfolioopt python library using binary weight (0,1) and weight sum (w =10) constraints

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, finance, quantitative-finance

```
import pandas as pd
from pypfopt.efficient_frontier import EfficientFrontier
from pypfopt import risk_models
from pypfopt import expected_returns

# Read in price data
df = pd.read_csv("tests/resources/stock_prices.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col="date")

# Calculate expected returns and sample covariance
mu = expected_returns.mean_historical_return(df)
S = risk_models.sample_cov(df)

# Optimise for maximal Sharpe ratio
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S)
weights = ef.max_sharpe()
ef.portfolio_performance(verbose=True)
```

I want to add weights only binary (0,1) and weight sum constraint to any variable(say =10)

Answer (score 0):

Then you should use `objective_functions` to replace the rest:

```
# Optimize for maximal Sharpe ratio 
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S)
weights = ef.nonconvex_objective(objective_functions.sharpe_ratio, 
    objective_args=(ef.expected_returns, ef.cov_matrix), constraints=[
        {"type": "eq", "fun": lambda w: np.sum(w) - 10},  # weight sum to 10
    ]
)
```

Weights will only be a figure between (0,1), but weight sum constraints to 10 normally is a bad idea, because it simply means your are investing weights to 1000%. However, you should get the idea from above.